Deploying ABP.io Blazor WebAssembly with Docker: Nginx Serves Default Page in .NET 8
I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy an ABP.io Blazor WebAssembly application using Docker. I'm following the official ABP.io documentation for Docker deployment, but I'm stuck with the default Nginx page instead of my Blazor app.
I'm following the deployment guide from the official ABP.io documentation:
ABP.io Docker Deployment Guide
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS build
COPY bin/Release/net8.0/publish/ app/
  
FROM nginx:alpine-slim AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/wwwroot .
COPY /nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

dotnet publish -c Release -p:PublishTrimmed=false 
docker build -f Dockerfile.local -t acme/bookstore-blazor:latest .

The Issue:
In .NET 8, there's no index.html file in my Blazor.Client project. As a result, when I deploy the application, I'm stuck with the default Nginx page instead of my Blazor app.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

you have to check by login into container.
and additionally you can follow this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu

Hi. I've created the newest version of ABP that has 2 projects: Blazor and Blazor.Client. I don't think I can use Nginx anymore with this setup
